# JavaFX Dialog Box (confirmation box) which is user can't skip

Tags: javafx-8

In my JavaFX application I want to pop up some dialog box (as confirmation box).
But I do not want to make chance user to skip that one.
That mean in many examples I have seen once Dialog Box is popup user can click out of that and can skipped it, then that dialog box is remains as it is ever.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a dialog [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) (i.e. block input to other application windows), call on the dialog stage:

[`dialogStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#APPLICATION_MODAL)

> Defines a modal window that blocks events from being delivered to any other application window.

OR

[`dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html#WINDOW_MODAL)

> Defines a modal window that block events from being delivered to its entire owner window hierarchy. Note: A Stage with modality set to WINDOW_MODAL, but its owner is null, is treated as if its modality is set to NONE.